# Is there a bigquery SQL script to return data based on an ordered list?

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say you have a sample table as follows:

| ID | MetaData | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Token 2 | Queen |
| A | Token 7 | Rook |
| B | Token 2 | Pawn |
| B | Token 1 | Bishop |
| C | Token 2 | Knight |

Let's say based on the metadata in the table, I may choose one data point over the other. Let's say we choose data associated with Token 7 first, Token 1 second, Token 2 third.

So the ideal output table is:

| ID | MetaData | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Token 7 | Rook |
| B | Token 1 | Bishop |
| C | Token 2 | Knight |

How would I write that query? I attempted to rank but the order of trust doesn't follow a numerical order. I also wanted to union tables together based on distinct metadata but that would mean there were duplicates.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want token 2 as the third row. But you have 3 rows with token 2 as MetaData. Why specifically the last?

Comment: Where do you have this "list" : ["Token 7", "Token 1", "Token 2"]  ? How long is it? you could save that list to a table with an index and then join that table to the other table. For union and preventing duplicated, you need to provide more information thus we can help you building a logic for that.